# Problem with postgres Function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote the following function to query data from tables and columns that I give as arguments:

```
create or replace function field_summaries(gap interval , _tbl anyelement, _col text)                                
 returns SETOF anyelement as 
 $func$   
 BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
 'select                                                                                                                       
 time_bucket(' || gap || ', time)::text as hour,                                                                                      
 avg(' || _col ||'),                                                                                                          
 min(' || _col ||'),                                                                                                          
 max(' || _col ||')                                                                                                         
 from ' || pg_typeof(_tbl) || ' d                                                                                                         
 where d.device_id in (                                                                                                       
     select device_id from sensors)                                                                                           
     group by hour';
 END
 $func$ language sql stable;
```

The problem is that when call the function like this:

```
select field_summaries('5minutes', NULL:: m_13, 'temperature');
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"  
LINE 2:  time_bucket(00:05:00, time)::text as hour,                 ...                                                                           
                       ^                                                                                                   
QUERY:  select                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
time_bucket(00:05:00, time)::text as hour,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
avg(temperature),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
min(temperature),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
max(temperature)                                                                                                           
from m_13 d                                                                                                                
where d.device_id in (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
select device_id from sensors)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
group by hour                                                                                                         
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function field_summaries(interval,anyelement,text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Does anyone have an idea of what this could be?

Comment: sorry it's func$ language plpgsql

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum. Please tag your PostgreSQL version. Is seems related to TimescaleDB, change `gap` datatype from `interval` to `text` enclosed in a single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is the fact that you just concatenate the parameter into the string. When using `EXECUTE`, parameters should be denoted using `$1, $2, ...` inside the string and the values should be passed with the `USING` clause of the `EXECUTE` command.

Additionally, dynamic SQL should be created using the [format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function. For one because it can properly deal with identifiers (using the `%I` placeholder). And it makes the SQL easier to read as well.

As the columns and their data types are fixed, I would also change the function to `returns table(...)` because that is easier to use later.

So the function should look something like this:

```
create or replace function field_summaries(gap interval , _tbl anyelement, _col text)                                
  returns table(hour text, average numeric, minimum numeric, maximum numeric) 
$func$   
begin
 RETURN QUERY 
  EXECUTE format('select time_bucket($1, time)::text as hour,                                                                                      
                         avg(%I), 
                         min(%I),
                         max(%I)                                                                                                         
                  from %I d                                                                                                         
                  where d.device_id in (select device_id from sensors)                                                                                           
                  group by hour', _col, _col, _col, _tbl)
     USING gap; --<< this passes the parameter to the EXECUTE command
END;
$func$ 
language plpgsql
stable;
```

You will need to adjust the data types of the output columns in the `returns table()` part.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have another question: Could I call the function using a text as the table name instead of NULL::tablename ? I need to enter the name as string when I call the function but when I do it it says table does not exist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. That's why using `format()` is recommended.

Comment: It seems to not work =/ For example when I call the function like this 'select fied_summaries('5minutes', NULL:: m_13, 'current')' it executes but when I do 'select fied_summaries('5minutes', 'm_13', 'current')' it throws an error that m_13 does not exist. My goal is to call the function like that. Is there away to make the NULL::m_13 call inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

Change `gap` datatype from `interval` to `text` and enclose it between single quotes in your dynamic query.

```
create function test (gap text)
returns text
as $ftest$
declare
    cmd text;
begin
    cmd := 'select ''' ||  gap || '''::interval';
    return cmd;
end
$ftest$ language plpgsql 

select test('5 minute');

test                        
:--------------------------
select '5 minute'::interval
```

```
select '5 minute'::interval

| interval |
| :------- |
| 00:05:00 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=047e8a731362249637e1d381ce291327)*